# Вторая нормальная форма

Tags: sql, база-данных

Никак не могу понять в чем заключается вторая нормальная форма. В заблуждение вводит еще и то, что в разных источниках немного отличная информация. Например, [здесь](https://stepik.org/lesson/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-1%D0%9D%D0%A4-2%D0%9D%D0%A4-3%D0%9D%D0%A4-%D0%9D%D0%A4%D0%91%D0%9A-27119/step/1?course=%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85&unit=8687) говорится, что для выполнения условия второй нормальной формы достаточно того, чтобы первичный ключ был не составным, а вот [здесь](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjAgLb45PrPAhWGEywKHfuTCoMQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi-novice.net%2F6-normalnyx-form-bd%2F&usg=AFQjCNHmkTXkrKmZywApeRo4K3iv7dwPrw&sig2=KmBSKK7oUedckfrTeRn2jg&bvm=bv.136811127,d.bGg) судя по тексту не важно составной или простой первичный ключ. Куда не смотрю, везде разные определения... Может кто-нибудь очень просто объяснить ?

Comment: По первой ссылке видно лишь «Предупреждение. Урок, который вы пытаетесь открыть, доступен в рамках курса "Введение в базы данных"», что именно там говорится — неизвестно. Но вообще говоря, приведенные в вопросе утверждения друг другу не противоречат. Первое утверждение — это уже следствие из определения, и речь там идет о том, что если таблица находится в 1-й НФ и имеет не составной ПК, то она автоматически будет находиться и во 2-й НФ. Но это не является необходимым условием.

Comment: Я еще не встречал теоретиков, которые спроектировали БД, используя термины "вторая форма, первая форма". Очень часто приходится приходить к денормализации для оптимизации БД под нагрузки.

Comment: @Yaant, а я и не говорил про необходимое условие....

Comment: Если в гугле забить "вторая нормальная форма" и почитать первые несколько ссылок (википедию обязательно), то что остается не ясным. Там в вики даже сказано, что ключ может быть составным, но в этом случае неключевые атрибуты не должны зависеть от части ключа

Comment: Возникает вопрос немного не по теме... Если мы приведем БД к первым трем нормальным формам, то получится много таблиц. `JOIN`, как я понимаю, операция дорогая. Нормальные формы часто замедляют работу СУБД, так ведь или я в чем-то ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Да, нормализация может замедлить работу из-за большого количество соединений. Поэтому, иногда делают денормализацию, применяют материализованные представления и т. п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отношение находится во второй нормальной форме если любой неключевой атрибут неприводимо зависит от потенциального ключа. Неприводимо означает в ключе от которого зависит этот атрибут нет подключа.

Это определение сформулировано для отношения в котором есть **ровно один потенциальный ключ**, однако таковых может быть несколько, например, суррогатный ключ - id, который генерируется автоматически, при добавлении такого ключа отношение не находящееся во второй нормальной форме, исходя из определения, вдруг становится таковым, что, вообще говоря неверно. Поэтому для того, чтобы определить находится ли отношение во 2-ой нормальной форме следует проверить вышеупомянутое определение для всех потенциальных ключей.

Comment: Проверять вышеупомянутое определение не обязательно для всех потенциальных ключей, а лишь для тех, в состав которых входит более одного атрибута.

Comment: @edem, простота ключа является очевидной достаточностью неприводимости

Answer (score 1):

Отношение (таблица), в котором **ключ** состоит **из одного столбца**, находится во второй нормальной форме (2НФ), если:

1. оно находится в 1НФ.

Отношение (таблица), в котором **ключ** состоит **из нескольких столбцов**, находится во второй нормальной форме (2НФ), если:

1. оно находится в 1НФ;
2. каждый столбец (атрибут), который не входит в состав ключа, целиком зависит от всего ключа.